# Retrofit converter with kotlin: type inference failed

Tags: generics, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to write a retrofit converter in kotlin. However, I stuck when trying to return the converters:

```
class JSONRPCConverterFactory private constructor(private val gson : Gson): Converter.Factory() {

    companion object {
        private val MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.get("application/json")

        fun create(gson: Gson) = JSONRPCConverterFactory(gson)
    }

    inner class JSONRPCRequestBodyConverter<T : JSONRPCRequest<*>>(private val gson: Gson) : Converter<T, RequestBody> {

        override fun convert(value: T): RequestBody? {
            val jsonString = gson.toJson(value, object:TypeToken<T>(){}.type)
            return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, jsonString)
        }

    }

    inner class JSONRPCResponseBodyConverter<T>(private val gson: Gson) : Converter<ResponseBody, T> {

        override fun convert(value: ResponseBody): T? {
            return gson.fromJson(value.string(), object:TypeToken<T>(){}.type)
        }

    }

    override fun responseBodyConverter(type: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
        if (!hasJSONRPCAnnotation(annotations)) return null

        return JSONRPCResponseBodyConverter(gson)
    }

    override fun requestBodyConverter(type: Type, parameterAnnotations: Array<Annotation>, methodAnnotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<*, RequestBody>? {
        if (!hasJSONRPCAnnotation(methodAnnotations)) return null

        return JSONRPCRequestBodyConverter(gson)
    }

    private fun hasJSONRPCAnnotation(annotations: Array<Annotation>) : Boolean {
        for (annotation in annotations) {
            if (annotation is JSONRPC) return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

The error comes in those two lines:

```
return JSONRPCResponseBodyConverter(gson)
```

and

```
return JSONRPCRequestBodyConverter(gson)
```

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in
>
> constructor JSONRPCRequestBodyConverter> ( gson:
>   Gson )
>
> Please specify it explicitly.

In Java, it is possible to return just `new JSONRPCResponseBodyConverter<>(gson)`. In kotlin however, the type is required, so adding just `<>` will fail as well.

Looking into this converter using Kotlin-lang: [Kotlin Serialization Converter](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/retrofit2/converter/kotlinx/serialization/Factory.kt), I saw that it uses nearly the same class structure and simply returns a new converter without the diamonds and it works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that both `JSONRPCResponseBodyConverter` and `JSONRPCRequestBodyConverter` require a type parameter `T` and the compiler is not able to deduce this type at the calling site. The example that you saw probably have some way of inferring the type of T, for example it's parameters or the type it is being asigned to.

```
class A<T>(t: T? = null)

val a1 : A<Int> = A() //this will work, it can infer the type from the asigment
val a2 = A(2) //this will work, it can infer the type from the parameter
val a3 = A() //this won't work, the compiler has no way of knowing the type of T
```

Comment: I added the link to the other converter, which I was referring to. As you can see, it does not pass explicitly any types. So, I assume, it will do it implicitly, but I can't see how and where.

Comment: in the example there are not type parameters. But if you look at the declaration of `SerializationStrategyConverter` the parameter can be infered by the type of the `saver`argument. While in the case of `DeserializationStrategyConverter` the type can be infered with the `loader`

Comment: That was the trick. Haven't seen that the loader has actually the same type.